# How to skip step in XPath?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is something like the following possible?

`/ul/.../p`

Answer (score 0):

Use abbreviated syntax:

> **//** is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/.

```
/ul//p
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Comment: I just want to skip one step, not to do a recursive search.  I think I need `/ul/*[1]/p`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to skip it like *this can be any element*?

```
/ul/*/p
```

[Xpath Abbreviated](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)